# Generation of polynomial features in C++98

Tags: c++, c++11, c++98

I am trying to generate polynomial features of an array of 27 floats to obtain an array of 405 floats as output. I am working on an old version of C++98 (no upgrade possible). I used to use this piece of code in C++11 to generate those features:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
//#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
std::vector<T> polynomialFeatures( const std::vector<T>& input, unsigned int 
degree, bool interaction_only, bool include_bias )
{
    std::vector<T> new_chunk; // declare new_chunk here
    std::vector<T> features = input;
    std::vector<T> prev_chunk = input;
    std::vector<size_t> indices( input.size() );

   for ( int d = 1 ; d < degree ; ++d )
    {
       for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < input.size() - ( interaction_only ? d : 0 ) ; ++i )
        {
            // Store the index where to start multiplying with the current component at the next degree up:
            size_t next_index = new_chunk.size();
           for ( auto coef_it = prev_chunk.begin() + indices[i + ( interaction_only ? 1 : 0 )] ; coef_it != prev_chunk.end() ; ++coef_it )
            {
                new_chunk.push_back( input[i]**coef_it );
            }
            indices[i] = next_index;
        }
        // Extend the feature vector with the new chunk of features:
        features.reserve( features.size() + std::distance( new_chunk.begin(), 
new_chunk.end() ) );
        features.insert( features.end(), new_chunk.begin(), new_chunk.end() );

        prev_chunk = new_chunk;
    }
    if ( include_bias )
        features.insert( features.begin(), 1 );

    return features;
}
```

And due to my limited Knowledge in C++, I am having difficulties to adapt this function in C++98. I tried the following by removing the vectors which I don't need:

```
float polynomialFeatures( float input[27], unsigned int 
degree, bool interaction_only, bool include_bias )
{
    float new_chunk; // declare new_chunk here
    float  features = input;
    float  prev_chunk = input;
    float  indices( input.size() );

   for ( int d = 1 ; d < degree ; ++d )
    {
       for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < input.size() - ( interaction_only ? d : 0 ) ; ++i )
        {
            // Store the index where to start multiplying with the current component at the next degree up:
            size_t next_index = new_chunk.size();
           for ( auto coef_it = prev_chunk.begin() + indices[i + ( interaction_only ? 1 : 0 )] ; coef_it != prev_chunk.end() ; ++coef_it )
            {
                new_chunk.push_back( input[i]**coef_it );
            }
            indices[i] = next_index;
        }
        // Extend the feature vector with the new chunk of features:
        features.reserve( features.size() + std::distance( new_chunk.begin(), 
new_chunk.end() ) );
        features.insert( features.end(), new_chunk.begin(), new_chunk.end() );

        prev_chunk = new_chunk;
    }
    if ( include_bias )
        features.insert( features.begin(), 1 );

    return features;
}
```

And I get those errors:

```
 In function 'float polynomialFeatures(float*, unsigned int, bool, bool)':
 error: cannot convert 'float*' to 'float' in initialization
     float  features = input;
                       ^
 error: cannot convert 'float*' to 'float' in initialization
     float  prev_chunk = input;
                         ^
 error: request for member 'size' in 'input', which is of non-class type 'float*'
     float  indices( input.size() );
 warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
    for ( int d = 1 ; d < degree ; ++d )
 error: request for member 'size' in 'input', which is of non-class type 'float*'
        for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < input.size() - ( interaction_only ? d : 0 ) ; ++i )
 error: request for member 'size' in 'new_chunk', which is of non-class type 'float'
             size_t next_index = new_chunk.size();   
 warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
            for ( auto coef_it = prev_chunk.begin() + indices[i + ( interaction_only ? 1 : 0 )] ; coef_it != prev_chunk.end() ; ++coef_it )
 error: 'coef_it' does not name a type
            for ( auto coef_it = prev_chunk.begin() + indices[i + ( interaction_only ? 1 : 0 )] ; coef_it != prev_chunk.end() ; ++coef_it )
 error: expected ';' before 'coef_it'
            for ( auto coef_it = prev_chunk.begin() + indices[i + ( interaction_only ? 1 : 0 )] ; coef_it != prev_chunk.end() ; ++coef_it )           
 error: 'coef_it' was not declared in this scope
 error: request for member 'end' in 'prev_chunk', which is of non-class type 'float'
            for ( auto coef_it = prev_chunk.begin() + indices[i + ( interaction_only ? 1 : 0 )] ; coef_it != prev_chunk.end() ; ++coef_it )               
 error: request for member 'push_back' in 'new_chunk', which is of non-class type 'float'
                 new_chunk.push_back( input[i]**coef_it );
 error: invalid types 'float[size_t {aka long unsigned int}]' for array subscript
             indices[i] = next_index;
 error: request for member 'reserve' in 'features', which is of non-class type 'float'
         features.reserve( features.size() + std::distance( new_chunk.begin(), 
 error: request for member 'size' in 'features', which is of non-class type 'float'
         features.reserve( features.size() + std::distance( new_chunk.begin(), 
 error: 'distance' is not a member of 'std'
         features.reserve( features.size() + std::distance( new_chunk.begin(), 
 error: request for member 'begin' in 'new_chunk', which is of non-class type 'float'
         features.reserve( features.size() + std::distance( new_chunk.begin(),                       
 error: request for member 'end' in 'new_chunk', which is of non-class type 'float'
 new_chunk.end() ) );
 error: request for member 'insert' in 'features', which is of non-class type 'float'
         features.insert( features.end(), new_chunk.begin(), new_chunk.end() );
 error: request for member 'end' in 'features', which is of non-class type 'float'
         features.insert( features.end(), new_chunk.begin(), new_chunk.end() );
 error: request for member 'begin' in 'new_chunk', which is of non-class type 'float'
         features.insert( features.end(), new_chunk.begin(), new_chunk.end() );    
 error: request for member 'end' in 'new_chunk', which is of non-class type 'float'
         features.insert( features.end(), new_chunk.begin(), new_chunk.end() );
 error: request for member 'insert' in 'features', which is of non-class type 'float'
         features.insert( features.begin(), 1 );
 error: request for member 'begin' in 'features', which is of non-class type 'float'
         features.insert( features.begin(), 1 );
```

I also would like to multiply each of the generated features during the features generation procedure with a coefficient of another array of floats with 405 values and add all of those multiplications to obtain at the end the scalar product of both arrays ( the polynomial features array 'features[405]' and the already known array 'abc[405]'

Comment: `std::vector` is a c++98 feature, you should keep it; Just remove `auto` keywords

Comment: @pptaszni ok didn't know that, but I don't really vectors I can work with simple arrays of floats

Comment: Here you go: https://godbolt.org/z/G79361 keep the vectors, there is no point struggling with manual memory management if you already have it in the library

Comment: @pptaszni But in case I want to use arrays does that cause a problem?

Comment: From the C++ runtime POV it is not a problem at all. It will cause a problem only for you, because you will always need to keep the array length somehow. It is not very common that array length can be known at compile time, even less common to always be 27.

Comment: @pptaszni If the input size is always 27 and the output size 405, how can I use arrays in the function instead of vectors?

Comment: `std::array` is available since C++11, so in your case you need the raw pointers. Like `void foo(float* arr);` or `void foo(float arr[FIXED_SIZE]);` [more examples](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array)

Comment: @pptaszni can you show me how would the function look like with arrays please

Comment: I showed already, the signature to accept the array is `void foo(float* arr);`; Or [example with const and template](https://godbolt.org/z/7vedTP)

Comment: @pptaszni I am not sure if I understand what you wrote correctly but by  using ` float polynomialFeatures( float* input, unsigned int 
degree, bool interaction_only, bool include_bias )` I still get errors everywhere in the function